# find length of longest side

Tags: geometry

let us consider    this problem:

A thin carpet of length $30$ ft was laid around a rectangular field of area $54$ sqft. if the carpet was exactly sufficient find the length of the longer side

is this figure right?

[image]

so  if we denote length and width by $x$ and $y$,then we have

$x+y=15$
$x*y=54$

sides are $9$ and $6$,because from first $x=15-y$
$y(15-y)=54$   or

$y^2-15*y+54=0$

$y_1=9$ and $y_2=6$; so $x_1=6$ and $x_2=9$,is it correct?

Comment: When you say a carpet of 'length' 30, do you mean perimeter 30? If so, then you're good.

Comment: actually it is meant yes when is given such kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks good (though your figure has mislabeled area). Based on your calculations, then, the longest side length would be...?